# How to replace ⅓ with 1/3 in a string to store in a database

Tags: c#

I want to change the fractions that look nice on a webpage, but when added to database through stored proc they produce a ?

This is the code I'm trying to get to work....the Contains() method works with the fractions and triggers but the Replace() doesn't replace :( Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
foreach (ListItem Item in lboxIng.Items)
        {
            fracCheck = Item.ToString();
            if (fracCheck.Contains("⅓"))
            {
                fracCheck.Replace("⅓", "1/3");
                listString += fracCheck;
            }
            else if (fracCheck.Contains("⅔"))
            {
                fracCheck.Replace("⅔", "2/3");
                listString += fracCheck;
            }
            else
            {
                listString += Item;
            }
            ingList.Add(listString);
        }
```

Comment: Why don't you instead change your database to allow a more modern character encoding?

Comment: This code doesn't need the if ( ... .Contains() ) statements. They are superfluous.

Comment: @WillemvanKetwich Not only superfluous, it will also fail (not work as expected) when the string contains both ⅓ and ⅔.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Replace` method does not modify the string, but returns a modified version of the string. So you need to assign the return value of `Replace` to the variable:

```
fracCheck = fracCheck.Replace("⅓", "1/3");
```

Short version of your code:

```
foreach (ListItem Item in lboxIng.Items)
{
    var fracCheck = Item.ToString();
    fracCheck = fracCheck.Replace("⅓", "1/3");
    fracCheck = fracCheck.Replace("⅔", "2/3");

    ingList.Add(fracCheck);
}
```

---

A much better approach is to change your database to use a unicode characterset, so that you can store any text in it.

Comment: I'm using VS 2017 SQL server 13 DB, how would i change to allow modern fractions?

Comment: how would i change to allow modern fractions?

Comment: @KyleThomas Most simple and straightforward solution: use nvarchar instead of varchar as datatype

Answer (score 1):

Or even shorter:

```
foreach (ListItem Item in lboxIng.Items)
{
    listString += Item.ToString().Replace("⅓", "1/3").Replace("⅔", "2/3");
    ingList.Add(listString);
}
```